# Pandas apply function to multindexed columns that takes columns (Series) as arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply a function that takes subcolumns (aka Series) of multiindexed columns as arguments. I have come up with a solution that works, but I was curious if there was a more pythonic/proper pandas way to do this.

Let's say we have a function that takes two series as arguments and performs some user-defined operation on those series and returns a single series.

```
import pandas as pd

def user_defined_function(series1, series2):
    return 12 * (series1 * series2 / 3)
```

Lets create a dataframe with multindexed columns.

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [10, 11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16, 17]]
columns = (('A', 'sub_col_1'),
           ('A', 'sub_col_2'),
           ('B', 'sub_col_1'),
           ('B', 'sub_col_2'))


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)

          A                   B          
  sub_col_1 sub_col_2 sub_col_1 sub_col_2
0         1         2         3         4
1         5         6         7         8
2        10        11        12        13
3        14        15        16        17
```

I want to appy my `user_defined_function()` to the sub columns of A and B.

Now if you try and use apply traditionally pandas will traverse each column individually returning a single series to the function. So you can't just do this.

```
df.apply(lambda x: user_defined_function(x['sub_col_1'], x['sub_col_2']))
```

You'll end up getting a key error because pandas is passing a series not a normally indexed "sub dataframe."

So this is the solution I came up with.

```
level1_labels = set(df.columns.get_level_values(0))
processed_df = pd.DataFrame()

for label in level1_labels:
    data_to_apply_function_to = df[label]
    processed_series = user_defined_function(data_to_apply_function_to['sub_col_1'],
                                             data_to_apply_function_to['sub_col_2'])
    processed_df[label] = processed_series

print(processed_df)

       A       B
0    8.0    48.0
1  120.0   224.0
2  440.0   624.0
3  840.0  1088.0
```

This returns what I want it to. However, I am curious if there is a cleaner, more pythonic, proper way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` over the columns axis. Your function requires a `Series` so we'll need to `squeeze` if we want to select by label.

```
(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
   .apply(lambda gp: user_defined_function(gp.xs('sub_col_1', level=1, axis=1).squeeze(),
                                           gp.xs('sub_col_2', level=1, axis=1).squeeze()))
)

#       A       B
#0    8.0    48.0
#1  120.0   224.0
#2  440.0   624.0
#3  840.0  1088.0
```

---

A bit more error prone, though fine if you know all groups have two Series in the same positions

```
(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
   .apply(lambda gp: user_defined_function(gp.iloc[:, 0], gp.iloc[:, 1]))
)
```

Comment: The second solution is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that this is a very custom case. It is actually possible to use `apply` within the 0 level columns as following

```py
import pandas as pd

# I just renamed it cos was very long
def udf(series1, series2):
    return 12 * (series1 * series2 / 3)

col = "A"
df[col].apply(lambda x: udf(x['sub_col_1'], x['sub_col_2']),axis=1)\
       .to_frame()\
       .rename(columns={0:col})
```

returns

```
       A
0    8.0
1  120.0
2  440.0
3  840.0
```

But again for the output you are looking for you should still need to loop.

```py
out = []
for col in set(df.columns.get_level_values(0)):
    out.append(
        df[col].apply(lambda x: udf(x['sub_col_1'],
                                  x['sub_col_2']),
                    axis=1)\
             .to_frame()\
             .rename(columns={0:col}))

out = pd.concat(out, axis=1)
```